# Rails: "Host A" URLs containing routes to serve pages on corresponding routes on "Host B"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes, host

**Using Rails: v 3.2.14**

I have following routes in my Rails application:

```
  get '/comment/:unique_id/' => 'controller#action'
  get '/:unique_id/thank_you' => 'controller#action'
```

The application is hosted on Heroku, say at following domain:

```
 http://jignesh-app.herokuapp.com
```

**My Requirement:**

*I want to map URLs with above routes, **but on different host**, 
  to serve the pages located at corresponding routes on http://jignesh-app.herokuapp.com.*

For e.g. Say I have a new host: http://www.jignesh-new-host.com.

Now when someone tries opening up the following URL:

```
http://www.jignesh-new-host.com/comment/:unique_id/
```

I want to display him the page served by URL

```
http://jignesh-app.herokuapp.com/comment/:unique_id/
```

Similarly, when someone tries opening up the following URL:

```
http://www.jignesh-new-host.com/:unique_id/thank_you
```

I want to display him the page served by URL

```
http://jignesh-app.herokuapp.com/:unique_id/thank_you
```

**Note:**

I don't want the URL to get changed in the browser's address bar.

For e.g. when I open up http://www.jignesh-new-host.com/comment/:unique_id/
the address bar should not change the URL to http://jignesh-app.herokuapp.com/comment/:unique_id/

*I don't know whether this is doable or not and hence posted my question here to get guidance on whether this is really achievable or not.If this is achievable, can anybody point me to the references to make this work?*

Thanks,

Jignesh